# How can I extract the maximum Von Mises stress in Abaqus on my entire assembly using python?

Tags: python, output, abaqus, odb

I've seen several examples on the internet of how to get the highest Von Mises stress from an instance. However, in my simulation there are 4 geometries (ie 4 instances) and my code is only evaluating the Von Mises stress in a single instance (disregarding the other three). Can anybody help me?

Put a "for" so that it would call the 4 instances, but even so it still insists on always getting 1 instance.

```
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from caeModules import *
from driverUtils import executeOnCaeStartup
from odbAccess import *
import numpy
import itertools
import math
import csv

odb = session.openOdb(job_name)
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=odb)
assembly = odb.rootAssembly
frame=-1

f2=odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[frame]

max_stress = 0

for name, instance in assembly.instances.items():
    f = f2.fieldOutputs['S'].values[0].instance.elements
    tam_elemento = len(f)
        
    print 'Instance: %s \n Elementos: %d'%(name,tam_elemento)

    for k in range(len(f)):
        element_mises_stress = f2.fieldOutputs['S'].values[k].mises
                 
        if element_mises_stress > max_stress:
            max_stress_element_label = f2.fieldOutputs['S'].values[k].elementLabel
            field_output_stress_object_index = k
            max_stress = element_mises_stress

print 'Mises: %f' % (max_stress)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, by default stress is output at the integration points. So, when you write

```
f2.fieldOutputs['S'].values[k].mises
```

You are NOT accessing the `mises` stress for `k`th element. You are accessing it for some integration point of some element (However, there is way to figure it out what node and what integration point). 
**Now, to get the maximum `mises` stress for entire assembly**.
You can get the maximum `mises` stress at integration point and centroid. let's see at the centroid.

```
import numpy
from abaqusConstants import *

# Getting stress at centroid of each element. 
# The values will be interpolated from integration points to the centroid of an element.
stressTensor = odb.steps['Step-1'].frames[-1].fieldOutputs['S'].getSubset(position=CENTROID)

# getting mises stress from Stress tensor
mStress = stressTensor.getScalarField(invariant=MISES,)

# Now use bulkDataBlocks to access the data as Numpy Array
dat = mStress.bulkDataBlocks[0]

# This has following attributes
print(dat.__members__)
#['baseElementType', 'componentLabels', 'conjugateData', 'data', 'elementLabels', 'instance',
# 'integrationPoints', 'localCoordSystem', 'mises', 'nodeLabels', 'position', 'sectionPoint', 'type']

# Get mises values and find max value
maxMies = numpy.max(dat.data)  # Maximum mises stress

maxIndx = numpy.argmax(dat.data) # Index of Maximum mises stress
elmLabel = stressTensor.values[maxIndx].elementLabel  # Element label of Maximum mises stress
elmInst = stressTensor.values[maxIndx].instance  # instance for the element
```